# Disable Aweber form popup on a specific page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, aweber

Hi can anyone help me disable or block Aweber form popup in two of my Wordpress page. By default this code is site wide and put under my footer.php.

```
<div class="AW-Form-306596914"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//forms.aweber.com/form/14/306596914.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-2vvzoocrg"));
</script>
```

Can I just put a CCS code on the page to disable the pop up or I need to edit the code itself?

Here's the two pages:

```
https://www.ataonline.edu.au/unlock-free-ebook-for-australia/
https://www.ataonline.edu.au/unlock-free-ebook-international/
```

I hope you can give me some idea on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add this condition

```
<?php if(!is_page('2870') && !is_page('2853')) { ?>

    <div class="AW-Form-306596914"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//forms.aweber.com/form/14/306596914.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-2vvzoocrg"));
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```